# What does the CPU consumption in top mean when a CPU is assigned to a single process?

Tags: linux, top, cpu-usage, benchmark, taskset

Being on Linux I have "CPUAffinity= 0 1 3" set in system.conf. I also use "taskset -cp 2 $pid" to assign a CPU to a single process.  But what does the CPU consumption  for the process in top now mean? Let's say it is 20%. Is it 20% for the single CPU or 20% for all CPUs?

Answer (score 0):

From `man`

> ´I´ :Irix/Solaris_Mode_toggle
>
> ```
>  When operating in ’Solaris mode’ (’I’ toggled Off), a task’s cpu usage will be divided by the total number of CPUs.  After issuing this command, you’ll be informed of the new
>           state of this toggle.
> ```

- while Irix ON - It shows the total usage of CPU for the task. ( sum of % of all CPU )
- while Irix OFF - It will show the usage of CPU per core for the task. ( % per CPU )